# How can I sum a date in SQL

Tags: sql

I have to do this:

1. the **Total amount of Jobs by Status** for the current day
2. the **Total amount of Jobs closed** in the last 30 days

My question is how to do that because I have been looking how to do it but I can't find it.

This is the corresponding data:

[image: the created table]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using and edit the question with a query showing your attempt to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select JobStatus, Count(*) as StatusCount 
from myTable 
where JobStartDate <= currentDate and currentDate < JobEndDate;


Select Count(*) as ClosedCount 
from myTable 
where JobStatus = 'C' and JobEndDate >= thirtyDaysAgo;
```

currentDate and thirtyDaysAgo are dependent to your database which you didn't tag.

Answer (score 0):

For question #1:

```
SELECT JOBSTATUS,COUNT(JOBID)
FROM BTRS_JOBS
WHERE JOBSTARTDATE <= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
AND JOBENDDATE > CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
GROUP BY JOBSTATUS
```

--YOU CAN USE ANY HARDCODED DATE

For question #2:

```
SELECT COUNT(JOBID) NOOFJOBSCLOSED
FROM BTRS_JOBS
WHERE JOBSTATUS = 'C'
AND JOBENDDATE >= CAST((GETDATE()-30) AS DATE) -- YOU CAN USE ANY HARDCODED DATE
```